# find successor in AVL tree

Tags: java, avl-tree

there is avl tree with nodes, and each node has only 3 fields:

1.right child

2.left child

3.value(key)

notice that it doesnt have such field "parrent" or "father".
my question is: in case we want to know the successor of EVERY node in the tree,
and without use any LinkedList or any collection, what is the method to do so?

Comment: Perform an infix traversal?

Comment: You're going to need some kind of stack, be it the call stack or an explicit stack.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
// Returns the last node in the inorder traversal of tree,
// or prev if tree is null.
Node printSuccessors(Node tree, Node prev) {
  if (tree == null) {
    return prev;
  }
  Node lastLeft = printSuccessors(tree.leftChild(), prev);
  if (lastLeft != null) {
    System.out.println("The successor of " + lastLeft.key() 
      + " is " + tree.key());
  }
  return printSuccessors(tree.rightChild(), tree);
}
```

and then call `printSuccessors(root, null)`.

Comment: how can i use it if i start from the most left leaf, that doesnt have
any children at all?

Comment: can you give me a hand here?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23723047/itertaor-in-avl-tree

Comment: If you start from the leftmost leaf, you can't do anything.  If you have no child pointers, then you have no way whatsoever of getting to the rest of the tree.